# Timeout issue generate wkhtmltopdf in symfony 2.4 knpSnappy bundle

Tags: php, symfony, timeout, wkhtmltopdf, exceed

When i download pdf using knpSnappy bundle , sometimes it's working proper and sometimes it's not working.

It generates errors like this:

> The process "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --margin-bottom '0'
>   --margin-left '0' --margin-right '0' --margin-top '0' --page-size 'A4' --disable-javascript --load-error-handling 'ignore' '/tmp/knp_snappy59521f8e31bad9.75401982.html'
>   '/tmp/knp_snappy59521f8e31c3d6.47962749.pdf'" exceeded the timeout of
>   60 seconds.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with the --lowquality argument ?

Comment: yes, I tried with this . But getting same error. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set a different timeout after creating a snappy instance like so:

```
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh');

$snappy->setTimeout(600);  // 600 seconds
```